# INSERT error using C#/Asp.Net/SQL RSS

Tags: c#

I have tried to insert data into a database using sqlparameters but I am unable to do that.. please help me..

```
a = "insert into Matsamp values(Login_Name,Password,Confirm_Password) values(@LName,@Pswd,@CPassword)";
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(a, con1);
        SqlParameter Uparm;
        Uparm = new SqlParameter("@LName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25);
        Uparm.Value = TextBox1.Text;
        cm.Parameters.Add(Uparm);

        string original;
        original = TextBox2.Text.Trim();
        int h = original.GetHashCode();
        string withHash = original;
        b1 = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(withHash);
        encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(b1);
        SqlParameter Pparam;
        Pparam = new SqlParameter("@Pswd", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300);
        Pparam.Value = Convert.ToString(encrypted);
        cm.Parameters.Add(Pparam);

        SqlParameter CPparm;
        CPparm = new SqlParameter("@CPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300);
        CPparm.Value = TextBox3.Text;
        cm.Parameters.Add(CPparm);
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("<Script>alert('inserted')</script>");
    }
        con1.Close();
```

Comment: What's the error you're seeing?

Comment: What happening when you execute? How do you know that it's not executing the query?

Comment: @Marco, I believe that's a TYPO ... not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

You query is wrong: probably it should be

```
a = "insert into Matsamp(Login_Name,Password,Confirm_Password) 
     values(@LName,@Pswd,@CPassword)";
```

And you could use

```
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", TextBox1.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pswd", ...);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CPassword", ...);
```

to make it shorter.